# $f$ be bounded continuous on $[0,+\infty)$, $f(x)=r$ has only finite solution for each $r$. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: calculus, continuity

$f$ be bounded continuous on $[0,+\infty)$, $f(x)=r$ has only finite solution for each $r$. Show that $f$ is uniformly continuous

Argue by contradiction, $\exists\ x_n,y_n\geq 0, |x_n-y_n|\to 0, |f(x_n)-f(y_n)|\geq \epsilon_0$. But the inteveral is not finite, Weierstarass could not be applied.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a different approach. Let $L_1=\liminf_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ and
$L_2=\limsup_{x\to\infty} f(x).$ If $L_1\lt L_2,$ then $f$ would cross ${1\over2}(L_1+L_2)$
infinitely often, a contradiction. Therefore, $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ exists, proving that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f(x_n)$ and $f(y_n)$ are bounded sequences, choose a common subsequence $n_k$ such that $f(x_{n_k}) \to L_1$ and $f(y_{n_k}) \to L_2$. Naturally, we have $|L_1 - L_2|\ge \varepsilon_0$. In fact, we can simply replace the sequence with this subsequence. Thus, we will assume $f(x_n) \to L_1$ and $f(y_n) \to L_2$, without loss of generality.

By swapping the sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ as necessary, assume $L_2 > L_1$. By rejecting initial terms of our sequence, we may also assume that
$$|f(x_n) - L_1| < \frac{L_2 - L_1}{3} \implies f(x_n) < \frac{2}{3}L_1 + \frac{1}{3}L_2$$
for all $n$. Similarly, we may also assume
$$f(y_n) > \frac{1}{3}L_1 + \frac{2}{3}L_2.$$
This means that the interval
$$\left[\frac{2}{3}L_1 + \frac{1}{3}L_2, \frac{1}{3}L_1 + \frac{2}{3}L_2\right]$$
is always contained in the interval $[f(x_n), f(y_n)]$. By the intermediate value theorem, this interval is therefore contained in $f[x_n, y_n]$, (i.e. the interval $[x_n, y_n]$ mapped under $f$).

Now, consider the point $(L_1 + L_2) / 2$. We know that this point is contained in all the above intervals, meaning that there is a point $z_n \in [x_n, y_n]$ such that
$$f(z_n) = \frac{L_1 + L_2}{2}.$$

Using the hypothesis, the value $(L_1 + L_2)/2$ is achieved finitely many times. This suggests that the sequence $z_n$ has a finite range (i.e. the same finitely many points on $\Bbb{R}$ end up just being repeated). By taking subsequences once more, we can actually assume $z_n$ is a constant $z \in \Bbb{R}$.

Recall that $z = z_n \in [x_n, y_n]$ for all $n$. Then,
$$x_n \le z \le y_n \implies 0 \le z - x_n \le y_n - x_n \to 0,$$
hence $x_n \to z$ by squeeze theorem (same for $y_n$). But, this contradicts the continuity of $f$, as we know that $f(x_n) \to L_1$ and $f(z) = (L_1 + L_2) / 2$, a different number to $L_1$. This gives us our contradiction, and so uniform continuity is proven.